# Change color image but don't change image behind in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have 2 image in canvas like this:

[image]
[image]

You can see this is 2 image transparent
In canvas it will show like this

[image]

I want to change color the 'Car' only .How to do that?

I was using dataImage to change color but it change the behind image too

My code :

```
 context.drawImage(imageObj,this.top,this.left,this.width,this.height);

 var imgData=context.getImageData(this.top, this.left, this.width, this.height);
    dataImg=imgData.data;
    for (var i=0;i<dataImg.length;i+=4)
    {
      dataImg[i]= hexToRgb(this.color).r |dataImg[i+2];
      dataImg[i+1]=hexToRgb(this.color).g |dataImg[i+2];
      dataImg[i+2]=hexToRgb(this.color).b|dataImg[i+2];
      dataImg[i+3]= 255;
    }
    context.putImageData(imgData,this.top, this.left);
```

Please show me some solution. TY

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the image color before composing the two images

```
context.drawImage(imageObj,this.top,this.left,this.width,this.height);
```

not after. Something like:

//draw background

```
context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
```

//create a fill of the color you want, use your image as a mask and add to the background

```
context.clearRect(this.top,this.left,this.width,this.height));
 context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
 context.fillRect(this.top,this.left,this.width,this.height));
 context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
 context.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I have a list image will auto draw. I don't think this way will work because I will need to know what image will be "background" when I choose a image to change color